# Creating a table whose fields are values returned of functions

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to create a table from values returned in Python Code using python-tabulate but I get failed!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tenant_consumption-ejem.py", line 25, in <module>
    menu()
  File "tenant_consumption-ejem.py", line 22, in menu
    print (tabulate(table, headers=["COLUMN1","COLUMN2","COLUMN3"]) )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tabulate.py", line 1109, in tabulate
12
    tabular_data, headers, showindex=showindex)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tabulate.py", line 820, in _normalize_tabular_data
    rows = list(map(list,rows))
TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable
```

Below you can see my python code in a simplified form to my actual code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
from tabulate import tabulate
def metodo1():
    p = subprocess.Popen("echo 10", shell=True)
    return p

def metodo2():
    p = subprocess.Popen("echo 11", shell=True)
    return p

def metodo3():
    p = subprocess.Popen("echo 12", shell=True)
    return p

def menu():
    exit = 1
    while exit != 0:
        print ("\nEscoja tu entrada: ")
        table = [metodo1(),metodo2(),metodo3()]
        print (tabulate(table, headers=["COLUMN1","COLUMN2","COLUMN3"]) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

Should I use another function to create tables ?, or should I modify the code somewhere? I can't create a table with return value fields as the code showed. Please any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please, replace your return statements with `return p.communicate()[0]`:

```
def metodo1():
    p = subprocess.Popen("echo 10", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    return p.communicate()[0]
```

If you want to get the data returned by the process, not the process itself (as you do now).

Comment: Hi @lenik As you suggested I changed **return p** to **return p.comunicate()[0]**  but it doesn't work yet. Now I have this error:  **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**. Any help please?

Comment: @JavierRichardQuintoAncieta you need `stdout=PIPE` argument in your call to `Popen()`, I'll fix the answer